# setInterval working only once when changing style in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i was trying to run this simple code which starts the Effect with the Button. The Effect should alternate the "highlight" or "shrink" class on each new setInterval tick (attach respective class to the div with id "effect" below), here is the html :

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="exercise">
      <!-- 1) Start the Effect with the Button. The Effect should alternate the "highlight" or "shrink" class on each new setInterval tick (attach respective class to the div with id "effect" below) -->
      <div>
        <button @click="startEffect">Start Effect</button>
        <div id="effect" :class="effectClasses"></div>
      </div>
```

here is the CSS :

```
 #effect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px !important;
}

.shrink {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

and this is the JS file :

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
        effectClasses :{
    highlight:false,
    shrink:true}
  },
  methods: {
    startEffect: function() {
    var vm = this;
    setInterval(function(){
       console.log('higlight 1:'+ vm.effectClasses.highlight);
        vm.effectClasses.highlight = !vm.effectClasses.highlight;      console.log('higlight 2 :'+ vm.effectClasses.highlight);

console.log('shrink 1 :' + vm.effectClasses.shrink);      
      vm.effectClasses.shrink =  !vm.effectClasses.shrink;
console.log('shrink 2 :' +vm.effectClasses.shrink);

    }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

the console logs are working fine but the style doesn't change every 1 second, which is weird

Comment: What do the console logs show? Does highlight 1 say true and highlight 2 say false and so on?

Comment: @MOHAMED Your code works as expected in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XGEJjm)

Comment: yes the console logs show that the values of highlight and shrink are changing between true and false

Comment: @tony19 thank you for your feedback your code seems to work